# CKAN instance for mostly private data?

Tags: ckan

I have been tasked to set-up a data portal for an organisation that develops large landscape restoration projects globally.

Many environmental and socio-economic datasets are collected and used throughout their operational cycles. The data portal will hold these datasets and a full range of organisational reports/information. For several reasons, most of these datasets/information are private and cannot be shared beyond the organisation.

CKAN looks perfect in that it meets all of the requirements for the data portal.

However, I am unsure whether CKAN only supports open-data projects (with minimal private data) or if I can use the software for a private organisation, for private data that cannot be shared? If it is the former (i.e. can only support open-data), please can you advise me of a similar software that is identical but can be used for private organisations.

Thank you in advance, and all my best
Becky

Answer (score 0):

CKAN is fine with datasets being set to private or public. Private ones can only be seen by someone logged in and attached the organization (there are other options too).

However it would be a bit weird to have it open to the world to see, listing 0 datasets, with a register link (only to still see 0 datasets, unless someone adds them to the CKAN organization). So the normal thing would be to host it on some organizational network, behind a firewall, and you don't have to worry about general public visibility. And if you then set datasets to 'public' then they are only visible across your real-world organization, because of the network restriction.